# How to load multiple images and text from server

Tags: android, image-processing, android-listview, e-commerce, lazy-loading

I am developing one application for one real state website. I have to display dynamic content from web I mean website display lots of images and description about the property. i need to populate images and their description in list view similar to flipkart android app do. I don't know how to proceed as of now i have thought i can download all images to sd card and get the text from json and then populate both in custom list. but i feel this is not a good approach as images grows in no it would take memory. Please give me some pointer how i should proceed to get better results.

Thanks in advance. Any help will appreciated.

Comment: for display images you can try [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use custom listview with image and text.
Get image and text both from web.
You can also refer to [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/).